# Two in one view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

In android I can have one Activity with a fragment layout. And then I can swap layouts inside the fragment. How might I accomplish the same effect in iOS?

Here is what I tried but got stuck along the way:

- In the parent ViewController `p1` I add a ContainerView as a holder for the views to be swapped. (Note that `p1` has other children views; not just the ContainerView)
- But of course a ViewController `c1` is auto-generated for (going inside) the ContainverView.
- so I was thinking that `c1` should be an abstract ViewController with two children ViewControllers `v1` and `v2`.
- so at this point I am trying to create segues from `c1` to `v1` and then from `c1` to `v2`. But I cannot create the segue: xCode won't let me. I try to restart Xcode but that didn't help. So is there a problem with Xcode or is what I am trying to do not allowed?

**For a bit more details**

`p1` has two buttons in addition to the ContainerView. If buttonOne is clicked I want the ContainerView to show, say, a horizontal TableView of ImageViews; but if buttonTwo is clicked then I want the ContainerView to show a vertical TableView of some custom TableView Cells.

In android I can accomplish this very simply by using two fragments: ImagesFragment, OtherDataFragment. Then I was swap the content of the `fragment` tag and voila!

Comment: @dasdom for someone with 6000+ reputation, you really didn't make any effort there.

Comment: What do you mean by xCode won't let you create the segue? Do you mean through storyboard? Or have you tried doing this programmatically

Comment: @LyricalPanda, through the storyboard: presently I am laying out the storyboard before touching the code portion.

Comment: @KatedralPillon Are you trying to use segues to keep a navigation stack within the containerView? Or just want the nice animations to go with it? I haven't heard or seen of anything like this before with segues inside the containerView. You can try having the ViewController set up in the storyboard outside of the ContainerView with its segue. Then in the containerView, instantiate the VC from the storyboard and try to perform a segue off it that way. I think that way the VC could keep its segue

Comment: @LyricalPanda what you said is what I have done: The ContainerView comes with an auto generated ControllerView. I refer to that ControllerView as `c1`. That ControllerView is what I have been trying to segue from, but somehow the storyboard refuse to make the connection: i.e. when I drop the line, it does not wire up. I was hoping someone could help me figure out why the storyboard is blocking me. I restarted Xcode, then I restarted my computer. But the problem persists.

Comment: you could accomplish that programmatically easily. But I don't know if we could do this in storyboard easily. It could be tricky. If you want to do programmatically, I could give you some heads up.

Comment: @RedDevil, I welcome the help. I made the assumption that I need a ContainerView. If that assumption is correct then my question is: how do I swap two ViewControllers v1 and v2. If my assumption is not correct: How else might I do this? Thanks.

Comment: your assumptions are correct. In code, [containerView.view addSubView:v1.view];   so If you need to add v2. [containerView.view addSubView:v2.view];

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at this example of a vertical tab bar controller. It shows how to create a custom segue to swap out the contents of a container view.

[Creating a Custom Side Tab Bar using Storyboards and Custom Segues](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-creating-a-custom-side-tabbar-using-storyboards-and-custom-segues/)

Comment: I also have a gist with the segue and controller here: (https://gist.github.com/AdamPro13/7540047)